# Internship over the summer

Tags: internships, newbie, work, film

I am a freshman at USC who is very much interested in sound design. I am currently working on two senior theses, and am also studying live sound. School ends May 11th and I am free till August. Los Angeles is my current location; however, I can relocate for the summer.
I am new to the 'industry' and don't really know anyone hiring sound design interns. Do you know of anyone who offers this sort of internship, or are you yourself in need of a summer intern? I can happily email you my curriculum vitae, portfolio list, or some of my work!
Thank you!
Larissa S.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Larissa,

In my last semester at USC (grad program), I did an internship at Danetracks, Dane Davis' sound company (Supervising Sound Editor on The Matrix trilogy, Ghost Rider, and Riding Giants amongst others). It was definitely an interesting and fun experience and you can learn a lot there. If you go to Danetracks' website, there's a link to the internship application there.

Comment: +1 I know at least one person who went through this and had a great experience.  Doesn't guarantee you'll be hired at the end, as I was told, but there are possibilities nonetheless.